# What is the real amount of data written in an hibernate file

Tags: memory, ssd, windows-8.1, hibernate

On a Windows 8.1 system with 32 GB of RAM + SSD with hibernation enabled, how must data is actually written to the hiberfil.sys file when the system is put in hibernation ?

My question is relative to the impact of hibernation on SSD aging: will Windows write all 32GB of RAM on file (even if a little memory is used when hibernation occurs), or will it be "smart" to only write useful data ?

Answer (score 2):

Windows only writes the the ram you actually use to your harddrive/SSD when you put it in hibernation mode. So yes, if you're using 30 GB of your ram, it will have to write the 30 GB to you SSD. But if you're only using 8GB, It will only write the 8GB to you SSD.